# UIWebView clips a page in half, zooming and panning don't work

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ios7, xamarin.ios

Tested this in iOS6 iPhone as well as iOS7 iPhone simulator. I have a simple UIWebView for displaying web pages, but for some reason, [this mobile page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1%252E0&rpsnv=2&ct=1387346535&rver=6%252E1%252E6206%252E0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%253A%252F%252Fdevprox%252Esharepoint%252Ecom%252F%255Fforms%252Fdefault%252Easpx&lc=1033&id=500046&guests=1&bk=1387346535) is clipped and only the right half is shown in Portrait mode. From trying to zoom or pan the page, I can tell that the UIWebView frame is correct, and that the page does not allow zooming out or panning, but it allows zooming in. If I then change to Landscape mode, then the page is framed correctly.

The UIWebView already have the following properties set:

```
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
webView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
webView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
```

In `LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)`, I check the `meta` tag with `name="viewport"`, and found the `content` to be reasonable:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes
```

The page shows up fine in iPhone Safari. What else can cause a web page to be clipped in UIWebView?

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I'm having the same problem with iOS8